# New Order of the Phoenix HQ

Tags: harry-potter

After the death of Dumbledore - who was the Secret Keeper of the headquarters' location at 12 Grimmauld Place - all members of the Order of the Phoenix became Secret Keepers, including Snape.

Since that moment, the Order obviously had to move out as it wasn't safe to operate from that location anymore - assuming they hadn't done it already, for example after Sirius' death.

**Where did the headquarters move to?**

Comment: Dunno about the downvote, this question looks ok to me.

Comment: It does, doesn't it @Voldemort? You would be most interested in the answer...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> They were often joined by other Order members for dinner now, because **the Burrow had replaced** number twelve, Grimmauld Place as the headquarters.
>
> (src: *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*,  Chapter Six,  The Ghoul in Pajamas )